# Move files from parent directories to subdirectories based on file extension

Tags: bash, shell

I have 139 directories that contain a subdirectory and files that need to be moved into the subdirectory.  I thought the simplest way to do this would be to use a mv command to recursively move the files based on their file extension of which there are only two. I have something like this:

```
xxx_03_001
 - xxx_03_001/xxx_03_001.csv
 - xxx_03_001/xxx_03_001.jpg
 - xxx_03_001/submissionDocumentation

xxx_03_002
 - xxx_03_002/xxx_03_002.csv
 - xxx_03_002/xxx_03_002.jpg
 - xxx_03_002/submissionDocumentation
```

I want:

```
xxx_03_001
 - xxx_03_001/submissionDocumentation/xxx_03_001.csv
 - xxx_03_001/submissionDocumentation/xxx_03_001.jpg

xxx_03_002
 - xxx_03_002/submissionDocumentation/xxx_03_002.csv
 - xxx_03_002/submissionDocumentation/xxx_03_002.jpg
```

How can I move these files recursively into the submissionDocumentation subdirectory within each parent directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this in the top level directory:

```
for dir in xxx_*; do
    mv "$dir"/*.{csv,jpg} "$dir"/submissionDocumentation/
done
```

Answer (score 0):

On the top level:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read dir
 do
 [ -d "${dir}/submissionDocumentation/" ] && find ${dir} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} ${dir}/submissinDocumentation/ \;
 done
```